# Naming conventions in the Android SDK

Tags: android, naming-conventions

Is there a publicly available document explaining the naming conventions followed in the Android SDK?

Comment: Use common naming conventions for icon assets http://stackoverflow.com/a/10785355/1012284

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Is it code style?
[Here](http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html) is a documentation from Google

Comment: I am more looking for naming conventions like how to name specific resources, like f.e. layout id's (underscored or camel-cased). Google doesn't seem to be consistent with them either..