# Android: Standards for prefixing files in the RES directory apart from ic_?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

anyone know if there a list of standard prefixes that we need to use (or advisable to use) in the RES directory. i.e. Android recommends ic_ for icons, which is great and i am following that.

But what about Logos, button images, navigation images etc?

I would really be interested to find out if other exist and what everyone else is using

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use common naming conventions for icon assets

Try to name files so that related assets will group together inside a directory when they are sorted alphabetically. In particular, it helps to use a common prefix for each icon type. For example:

```
Asset Type                   Prefix            Example
Icons                         ic_                ic_star.png
Launcher icons                ic_launcher        ic_launcher_calendar.png
Menu  and Action Bar icons    ic_menu            ic_menu_archive.png
Status bar icons              ic_stat_notify     ic_stat_notify_msg.png
Tab icons                     ic_tab             ic_tab_recent.png
Dialog icons                  ic_dialog          ic_dialog_info.png
```

check this link [tips for Designers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html#design-tips)

Comment: so basically just `ic_logo`, or `ic_logo_login`, `ic_login_welcome` (if there are multiple images) and so on